# remove numbers and characters from file

Tags: regular-expression

I have a file like below:

```
chs_de_le_q1gg
dsdas_212
sdasd_4567
weqwe_32323
dasds_232322
rr_F3r4
we_ff
asdasd_1_fff
sdfsd_tr
dsd_fr
```

I need to remove the lines ending with digits ranging from 4-8 of length; also to remove lines ending with ff and fr.

i couldnt do for numbers and letters together

```
cat test.txt |  grep  -vE "_[0-9]|[^0-9][0-9]{1,8}$\|_ff$|_fr$"
```

Can someone help?

output

```
dsdas_212
chs_de_le_q1gg
rr_F3r4
asdasd_1_fff
sdfsd_tr
```

Comment: Hello, could you add an expected output, as you are asking to remove lines ending with `ff` or `fr` but in your regular expression you are adding `_` in front of it

Comment: done. pls check; yes words ending with _fr , _ff, and _numbers

Comment: Ok now I got a question for the ranging numbers, you are saying `from 4-8`, is it from 4-8 or is it `_` followd by a number and a ranging of 4-8 numbers. Plus if it is an `_` followed by a number does it need to be in the last field (considerate `_` as a field separator) ?

Comment: _numbers ending which ranges from 4 to 8

Comment: Why is `dsdas_212` removed? That ends in 3 numbers (212), which is less than 4 so if you mean "remove line with four or more numbers at the end of the line", it should have remained. If you mean you want to remove lines if the last character of the line is a number between 4 and 8 then that still should not have been removed since 2 is less than 4. Please edit your question and clarify.

Comment: OK, thanks for the edit. So what operating system are you using? Can we assume you have GNU `grep` (the default on Linux systems) or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Extended Regular Expression you are looking for:

```bash
_[[:digit:]]{4,8}$
_f[fr]$
```

So using grep :

```bash
grep -Ev -e '_[[:digit:]]{4,8}$' -e '_f[fr]$' test.txt
```

Or using sed, you can add `-i` to apply change to the file directly

```bash
sed -E -e '/_[[:digit:]]{4,8}$/d' -e '/_f[fr]$/d' test.txt
```

- `-E` using Extended Regular Expression
- grep `-e` search all given pattern
- sed `-e` add script to the commands to be executed
- `[:digit:]` a digit
- `{4,8}` from 4 to 8
- `$` End of line
- `[fr]` either `f` or `r`

---

If you need too add a regular expressions you need to add `-e` with you regular expressions. You can add much as you want `-e` so don't overcomplicate you regular expressions.
So in your case you can add for br, bd, rt :

```bash
_br$
_bd$
_rt$
```

Comment: grep -Ev -e '_[[:digit:]]{4,8}$' -e '_f[fr]$' test.txt
Can you pls give me sample for adding br, bd rt etc for exclusion too?

Comment: @rose updated my answer

Comment: @rose if you have more requirements *please put them in your question*! Otherwise, people waste their time and yours giving you answers that don't do what you need.

Comment: @terdon, apologies, i didnt know there was a shortcut for ffr, thats why asked for more question.

Answer (score 1):

```
.*(\d{4,8}$|f[fr]$)
```

This says "any number of characters (.*) followed by 4-8 digits (\d{4-8) at the end of the line ($), or followed by f and one of f or r (f[fr]) at the end of the line(4)"

A simpler and extendible way:

```
.*(\d{4,8}|ff|fr|br|cu)$
```

In general new endings can be added in by putting them inside the (), separated by another "|"

I figured this out by going to **https://regex101.com/**, putting in your sample file, and messing around for a couple of minutes. **It's a great tool.**

Comment: thanks but can you separate ff and fr pls ? i have similarly 10  options to exclude ( br, bn, nm etc) , also how to use in grep ?

Comment: This could be simplified to `(\d{4,8}|f[fr])$`, we don't need `.*` to match the whole line as we only have to consider line endings; as all pattern in the capturing group should occur at the end of the line we also only do need `$` once succeeding the capturing group.

Comment: Note that this requires PCRE regular expressions which are not supported by all tools. You can use it in GNU `grep` with `-P`, but other grep implementations don't have it.

Comment: The best part of my advice is to learn about regex101.

Comment: Regex101 is great, but you need to know what kind of regex you will be working with.